# JS-style alert box in java

Tags: java, swing, popup, alert

What's the Java Swing counterpart for the JavaScript `alert()` popup (if there is one)?

Comment: Are you referring to a [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)?

Comment: Not sure what that is...

Comment: Aah, thanks! Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Others have given similar answers -- please upvote their answers and select one as the correct one. Much luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An basic way to accomplish such a popup is to use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`, [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "here comes the text.");   
// assumes frame to be a reference to the desired parent frame
```

Comment: How would I make that pane pop up (e.g. when a button is clicked, what code do I use to handle the event?)?

Comment: @Bluefire You may attach an `ActionListener` to your `JButton`, [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Answer (score 2):

Think you are looking for JOptionPanes but here is a good description of the different dialogs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 2):

How to create a dialog box in Java:

- [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) (The Java Tutorials)
- [Java - How to create a custom dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789517/java-how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box) (stackoverflow answer)