# JOptionPane Custom Buttons to return String

Tags: java, button, insert, joptionpane

I have a method getDate which returns String value. I'd like to add custom buttons but I can't because Eclipse tells me to change method type to int instead of String. What can I do here?

```
public String getDate(String info){
          return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, info, "Date insertion", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
```

This is how this InputDialog looks like:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rokad.png)

I want this dialog to have let's say Yes/No/Quit buttons and if I understand correctly, code like this should work:

```
public String getDate(String info){
      return JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,info,
                "Date insertion", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,options,
                null);
}
```

But it says "cannot convert from int to String" and I need it to return String not int.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` return int 0,1,2 depending on selected option .

Comment: But first code that I showed you returns String.

Comment: i don't understand your question clearly .but your first method is correct 2nd one is not correct.

Comment: I could do the same thing with 2nd method but I still need program to return the input value and not only 0/1/2 depending on options. Let's say: it returns 0, then it should also return input value. Any other button is exit the program.

Comment: what is `options` ?if you show a yes/no option dialog what is the input??

Comment: Nevermind. Is it possible to make an input dialog with custom options by using JOptionPane? I just want that user could input some info and send it  by pressing first option. And second option would exit the dialog.

Comment: yes you can.you can .read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789517/java-how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

Have the class that invokes `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` get the integer that it returns, and use that to choose the string that you want to return. You cannot change the `showOptionDialog()` method to return a string, but you can decide, based on the int that it returns, what string you want the caller to get. There's no need for a custom dialog.

```
public String getDate(String info)
{
  int[] optionStrings = { "Yes", "No", "Cancel" };
  int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, info, "Date insertion",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,options,
                        null);
  return optionStrings[option];
}
```