# Can I bind the return to a condition?

Tags: return, delay, imageicon

I have the following problem:
My method opens a JDialog with a bunch of buttons (only one in example code). I want to click a button and thereby choose an ImageIcon for my method to return. But the Method does not wait for me to click a button. It opens the window and then returns an empty ImageIcon.

```java
public class Kartenauswahl {

    ImageIcon bandit;

    public ImageIcon auswahlfenster() {

        int bwidth = new Integer(150);
        int bheight = new Integer(225);

        bandit = new ImageIcon("cover/Bandit.jpe");
        bandit.setImage(bandit.getImage().getScaledInstance(bwidth,bheight,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

        final JDialog kartenwahl = new JDialog();
        kartenwahl.setTitle("Kartenwahl");
        kartenwahl.setSize(1500,1000);
        kartenwahl.setVisible(true);
        kartenwahl.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ImageIcon returnicon= new ImageIcon();
        final JButton b1 = new JButton(); //just to get the Icon out of the void loop





        JButton B1 = new JButton(bandit); //this is going to be the button I want to click to choose the ImageIcon which is returned
        B1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        B1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                b1.setIcon(bandit);
                kartenwahl.dispose();
            }

        });

        kartenwahl.add(B1);

        returnicon = (ImageIcon) b1.getIcon();

        return returnicon;

    }
}
```

Question: can I bind the return statement to a condition? Like "only return after I clicked that Button B1"?

Comment: Thats the whole purpose of your actionevent.

Comment: Is that a question? In that case the answer is Yes!

Comment: Otherwise I don't understand what you are trying to say. If the ActionEvent delays the return, why doesn't my method work then?

Comment: The eventhandler in your case: actionPerformed. Will only run when the user clicks the button that the evenhandler is lisining to (B1). Now i see you have a second button b1. And that is the button you are setting the icon for in your eventhandler. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: I can not return the ImageIcon directly from the EventHandler, since it is a void method. So I have to set it to an exterior ImageIcon. Since I can't access an exterior variable from a void method (at least that is the exception I got when I tried) I go the way over Button b1. By the time I send the ImageIcon to b1 and thereby the "returnicon" the method will have already returned the empty "returnicon".

Comment: Ok i don't really understand why you're trying to pass along an image icon. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I need the ImageIcon in another class to set it onto another button. It's a bit complicated :D I don't have enough reputation to chat, sadly, otherwise I could get into detail.

Is there any way to return it after I initiate the event from the eventhandler?

Comment: The thing you are describing sounds like a Dialog. A pop-up window that the user has to click before the code will continue. In your case a custom Dialog should do the trick. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789517/java-how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box).

Comment: All this happens in a JDialog. Is that different from a CustomDialog? The Dialog needs to contain around 26 Buttons of the size 150,225. A simple YES_NO_Option won't do.

Comment: I have tried a ConfirmDialog, but it just puts the 26 Buttons underneath each other, so I can't see 24 of them. Can I align them in rows of 7 or 8?
Code:

     final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[]{
    B1, 
    B2,
    B3,
    B4,
    B5,
    B6,
    B7,
    B8,
    B9,
    B10,
    B11,
    B12,
    B13,
    B14,
    B15,
    B16,
    B17,
    B18,
    B19,
    B20,
    B21,
    B22,
    B23,
    B24,
    B25,
    B26,
  };
  JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputs, "Kartenwahl", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry for the long wait. I have written an custom JDialog that should work for you.

```java
public class CustomDialog extends JDialog {
    JButton[] buttons;
    ImageIcon selectedImageIcon;

    public CustomDialog() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 6));
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                selectedImageIcon = ((ImageIcon) ((JButton) e.getSource()).getIcon());
                dispose();
            }
        };
        buttons = new JButton[24];
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(new ImageIcon("path_to_your_image_file"));
            buttons[i].addActionListener(actionListener);
            add(buttons[i]);
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public ImageIcon getSelectedImageIcon() {
        return selectedImageIcon;
    }
}
```

The initial size is not that important the GridLayout is. you mentioned that you would need 24 buttons so I created an grid with 4 rows and 6 columns.
Then I create the buttons in a loop and adding the same Listener to set the selection icon with the icon of the pressed button. Afterwards I dispose the screen triggering an windowClosed event.

You could simply create this Dialog from your main class and wait for the response like so:

```java
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog();
        customDialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                ImageIcon icon = customDialog.getSelectedImageIcon();
                //do something with your icon
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it fixes your problem.
Have a good one!